Blender does not interact with google sheets
Is it possible to create a simple warehouse layout that would interact with google sheets?
I need to to some sort of "digital twin" and blender striked me as sufficient. Basicaly i need to see current products, expiry dates and amounts on specific warehouse locations, that can change dynamically based on how the user change the data in the google sheet - final product should be a simple 3D program that would provide me with informatin just by clicking on the cube (representing the warehouse location).
Is it even possible with blender? I am looking forward to tips and tricks.
